# "std::logic_error" when implementing Stack in C++

Tags: c++, class, new-operator

Not proficient with C++, I am trying to implement stack using C++ classes and here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class myStackElement {
    private:
        string Data;
        myStackElement* prev;
    public:
        myStackElement(string myData, myStackElement* head) {
            Data = myData;
            prev = head;
        }
        string popped(myStackElement* head) {
            head = prev;
            return Data;
        }
        string top() {
            return Data;
        }
};

class myStack {
    private:
        myStackElement* head;
    public:
        myStack() {
            head = NULL;
        }
        void push(string myData) {
            myStackElement* temp = new myStackElement(myData, head);
            head = temp;
        }
        string pop() {
            if(head == NULL) {
                return "0";
            }
            else {
                myStackElement * const temp = head;
                string popped = head->popped(head);
                delete temp;
                return popped;
            }
        }
        string peek() {
            if(head == NULL) {
                return "0";
            }
            else {
                string top = head->top();
                return top;
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    myStack hello;

    hello.push("other");
    string top = hello.peek();
    cout << top << endl;

    hello.push("another");
    top = hello.peek();
    cout << top << endl;

    string popped = hello.pop();
    cout << popped << endl;
    top = hello.peek();
    cout << top << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
other
another
another
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Interesting thing is that **if I don't `peek` after `popping`, the code works fine** (prints first three lines). So, I think my `head` pointer is getting messed up after popping.

It may be related to wrong usage of `delete` operator. But, I haven't used them enough to know.

The code above is first attempt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `pop` method never updates `head`, because the `head` variable you see in `popped` has only local scope. You can easily verify this by stepping through the function in a debugger and examining the value of `head`. If you want a function to change the variable you pass as an argument, you need to pass it by reference or pointer (which in this case means `myStackElement*&` or `myStackElement**`)

Comment: @Useless yes that was the problem. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/E13hE3Tof

Comment: @MarekR thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discusses in comments, the head pointer is not being updated in popped function to change a pointer I need to pass a pointer or reference to that pointer.

```
string popped(myStackElement** head) {
            *head = prev;
            return Data;
        }
```

and

```
string pop() {
            if(head == NULL) {
                return "0";
            }
            else {
                myStackElement * const temp = head;
                string popped = head->popped(&head);
                delete temp;
                return popped;
            }
        }
```